# CakePHP administrator routing

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am having a hard time to understand this admin-routing of CakePHP. From the Cookbook:

"You can map the url /admin to your admin_index action of pages controller using following route:"

```
Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true));
```

What is not clear to me is the "'admin' = true". What is the purpose of this? When you call logout-function, do you pass the argument "'admin' = false" to redirect function in AppController?

When you have multiple prefixes in use, do you use "'manager' = true" if you want to enable manager-prefix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`admin=true` in a route means your url is prefixed with `/admin`.

So in your example, your `/admin` route actually connects to: `/admin/pages/index`, and is serviced by the `admin_index()` action in your pages controller (as opposed to the non-prefixed `index()` action).

You can either ensure all links to logout are created with `admin=false` so they map to the standard `Users::logout()` action, or create a new action `admin_logout()` which handles admin logouts.

Adding `manager=true` to a url (along with the associated prefix setting) means the url with begin with `/manager`, and will map to `manager_...()` functions in the controller.

You can use both (or more!) prefixes, but not in the same url.

`/pages/index` maps to: `PagesController:index();`

`/admin/pages/index` maps to: `PagesController:admin_index();`

`/manager/pages/index` maps to: `PagesController:manager_index();`

Answer (score 2):

### Router Prefixes

In CakePHP 2.x prefixes changed a little.

You can have multiple prefixes now, but they have to be declared in the `core.php` file.

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin','api','json'));
```

That would declare 3 prefixes, and there is no need to modify the routing tables to make them work. The word `prefix` means it's placed before the name of the action when dispatching to the controller.

For example;

```
class DocumentsController extends AppController
{
     public index() { ... }
     public admin_index() { ... }
     public api_index() { ... }
     public json_index() { ... }
}
```

CakePHP will call the correct action when one of these URLs are request.

```
http://example.com/documents/index
http://example.com/admin/documents/index
http://example.com/api/documents/index
http://example.com/json/documents/index
```

What you can not do is use more than one prefix at a time. The following will NOT work.

```
http://example.com/admin/json/documents/index
```

That would require custom routing, because CakePHP doesn't know which action to call.

When an action is called you can which for prefixes in the request params.

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
   if(isset($this->request->params['admin']))
   {
        // an admin prefix call is being made
   }
}
```